# Find out what Version of MT and Mono an App was built with?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to tell from the app bundle what version of monotouch and mono was used for a specific app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
$ pwd
/Users/sebastienpouliot/src/TestCase/bin/iPhone/Debug/TestCase.app

$ cat version.cs
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine (MonoTouch.Constants.Version);
    }
}

$ /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs version.cs -r:monotouch.dll

$ MONO_PATH=. mono version.exe
4.2
```

You can infer the version of Mono from the version of MonoTouch (4.x uses 2.10, 3.x used 2.6). Note that this could fail if the linker eliminated Console.WriteLine.

Comment: Err, no, that's not what I meant. If I have already a built application (an app file), how can I find out what version of MT was used to build it?

Comment: Check again :-) The code above is **built** and **executed** against the monotouch.dll that is **included** in your existing .app directory. As such the printed version will be the monotouch version that was used to build your application (and not the one from the monotouch installed).

Comment: Aaaahh! Enlightenment! :-)  Thanks!